# ng-repeat end & start sliding animation

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-animation

I created this toggle menu [`template`](http://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/ZLeJLp) but i have problem implementing this [`sliding-animation`](http://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/WRjBRw). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you explore your requirment  so i can help you ?

Comment: i would like to make a menu with a sliding effect same like the `https://material.angularjs.org/latest/` sidebar menu, thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

For animated side bar you can use bootstab accordian with ng-repeat

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/